Can't parse properly the hour minute seconds from string to datetime in Dart
I can format the time in my desired format "3:38 PM" but it's a string type. But I want my to DateTime for later calculations. I can't manage to parse them. I want to remove this "1970-01-01" from the datetime 1970-01-01 03:38:00.000
I want this string to "3:38 PM" -> this DateTime "03:38:00.000". How can I do that?
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  String timeStr = "3:38 PM";
  try {
    DateTime parsedTime = DateFormat("HH:mm a").parse(timeStr);

    print(parsedTime); // 1970-01-01 15:38:00.000

    String formattedTime = DateFormat("h:mm a").format(parsedTime);

    print(formattedTime); // Output: 3:38 PM
  } catch (e) {
    print("Invalid time format");
  }
}


As said in the class you're using, it's a DateTime, so it's using a date alongside the time of the day, which defaults to 1970-01-01. If you only need hours and minutes (so no seconds, milliseconds...), you could be using TimeOfDay class:
TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(DateFormat("HH:mm a").parse(timeStr));

